What would cause one of my wires on my Electric Water heater Reliance 606 to burn and almost catch fire in the top panel and how to repair?
I had to change some piping on my Electric water heater that is a 40 Gallon Reliance 606 and after I replaced the pipe I started to notice a burning smell and noticed that one of the wires in the top panel which is yellow is actually starting to try and burn for some reason and it Melted the plastic around the wire as well  but that was the only wire that burnt So can somebody please help me by letting me know what could cause this? and how can I repair it?

a loose connection.

high resistance connection ... the wires should be bent around the screws for better contact

What causes that is NEC 110.14(D) Use a Torque Screwdriver, or rather, failure to do so.  Recent science shows torque matters even on the small stuff.
That entire black thing with 3 apparent sections is a thermostat assembly.  They're cheap, swap the whole thing.
While you're buying water heater parts, think about the sacrificial anode.  Like museum ships, they'll last well beyond their design life if you keep changing the anodes.

A loose connection on a high draw device (a water heater) will cause a point of high resistance and create heat. Enough heat that can cause the plastic to melt.
To repair it you'll need to replace the terminal block. cut back the wire with the molten insulation to a "clean" part. Or replace the wire with one of equal size. Check the torque spec on the terminals and follow them.

The rust on the element below it might have help also.

The "terminal block" is the thermostat. Should check the lower one as well.

Okay so with that yellow wire I think I might have enough there in order to cut off the molten  insulation to a clean part of the wire or at least it looks like I might have enough there??

How much does a thermostat usually cost? and do you think that the part that all the wires are screwed to in the picture there would need to be replaced or do you think I could possibly get by with cleaning the wire up and make sure all the screws are tightened?
